# Passing variable to SQL Action

Tags: powershell

I am comparing users from two different databases, and attempting to deactivate a user account in Database B if it is deactivated in Database A.  My query of Database A returns a list of user(s) that have expired accounts, and I can find a match in Database B.  But when I pass the variable on to deactivate the account in Database B, it doesn't.  I can run the SQL query directly on Database B in SQL Management Studio, as long as I type in the actual user ID, and it deactivates the account.

Here is the code I am using.  The $user.samaccountname is the user ID from Database A that has expired, and $ica.userid is a query of Database B:

```
foreach($user in $unity){
    if ($user.SamAccountName -in ($ica.userid))
    {
            
        $update=
@"
            USE IRWSDB
            UPDATE IRUser
            SET Active = 0
            WHERE UserID = '$user.samaccountname'
"@
```

Comment: Replace `'$user.samaccountname'` with `'$($user.samaccountname)'`

Comment: That doesn't seem to be doing the trick either.  Although in Powershell ISE I can see where the variable $user.samaccount name is displaying the test account I have set to expire, and it does match the userid in Database B.

Comment: But what happens? Does the SQL server return an error? Does PowerShell throw an error? Database updating the wrong user row? Please be mindful that only you can see your screen :)

Comment: When I run the script in Powershell ISE, it does not return any error or value.  When I open the SQL Management console on Database B, I use the same lines except I am not "smart" enough to set and pass the variable in the SQL query, so I manually enter the userid as plaintext, and it does disable the selected account.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
       foreach($user in $unity){
        if ($user.SamAccountName -in ($ica.userid))
        {
        $sam = $user.SamAccountName
        $update=
```

@"
USE IRWSDB
UPDATE IRUser
SET Active = 0
WHERE UserID = '$($sam)'
"@